# C# client - how would I communicate / interact with a CGI script running on a server?

Tags: c#, cgi

I'm probably totally betraying my ignorance at this point, but I have pretty much zero background in web programming, so I'm flying blind.

There's a web-based interface to an application here at work I'd like to knock up a quick client to, for a couple of reasons I won't bother going into. My client will be written in C#, and the web URL points to some CGI script that I assume runs on a server somewhere, interacts with the application via command line, then returns some results which are displayed on the web page.

Essentially, I'd like to write a C# client app that simply replaces the browser as the viewer for the results. I'm assuming I'd be communicating with the CGI script using HTTP, I'd be getting back my results which I could then parse and use however I want?

Does anyone have any links to a decent starting resource for this, or can anyone confirm that this is possible? Or is my mental model of this situation completely inaccurate?

Again, apolgies for my almost total web-ignorance.

Comment: I need exact same thing,  but the C= is inside of a Xamarin.forms project.   Did you ever find a solution to this?   Please share if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into webrequest/webresponse. Those should get you on the right track. They allow you to make web requests similar to how you would with a browser.

Comment: Tried this and ot just retrives some header type i fo but does not execute cgi page as the page runs in reg broweser.